# Multiple series barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have matrix the looks like this (expect with four numeric variables)

```
GeneId<- c("x","y","z")
Var1<- c(0,1,3)
Var2<- c(1,2,1)

df<-cbind(GeneId, Var1,Var2)
```

What I what to plot is a bar graph where each gene has a bar for each variable grouped (i.e x would have bar1 = height 0, bar2 = 1)
I can do individual graphs by writing a loop and plotting each row:

```
for (i in 1:legnth(df$GeneId){
  barplot(as.numeric(df[i,]), main= rownames(df)[i])
}
```

But I would like to have the plots on the same graph. Any ideas? I thought of doing using either `ggplot2` or `lattice` but from what I have seen they are only able to put them in a grid together, axis are independent of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df=data.frame(GeneId=c("x","y","z"), Var1=c(0,1,3),Var2=c(1,2,1))

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df_ = melt(df, id.vars=c("GeneId"))
ggplot(df_, aes(GeneId, value, fill=variable)) +
geom_bar(stat='Identity',position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: One more question, is there anyway to fix the order so the the bars a plotted in Var1, Var2 order rather then based on value?

Comment: If you change the value column to numeric class then this fixes the problem of ordering.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer would be to use

```
barplot(rbind(Var1,Var2),col=c("darkblue","red"),beside = TRUE)
```

I recommend you to read and experiment using [barplot](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html)